# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'

Tags: python, pip, modulenotfounderror, six

I have changed PC and downloaded all new packages etc. I am running a simple code to connect to linkedin and send messages but I got this error message Print Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/Users/olga/.vscode/extensions/xirider.livecode-1.3.10/node_modules/arepl-backend/python/arepl_python_evaluator.py", line 11, in <module> 
    import astunparse
  File "/Users/olga/.vscode/extensions/xirider.livecode-1.3.10/node_modules/arepl-backend/python/astunparse/__init__.py", line 3, in <module> 
    from six.moves import cStringIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves`
```

Any idea why?

I am using Python 3.12 and I have made sure even the `six` package was the latest, when checking through CMD I see it, but when running keeps telling me it doesn't work.
Here my full code:

```py
from bot_studio import *
linkedin=bot_studio.linkedin()
linkedin.login(username='janedoe@gmail.com', password='xxx5thh') 
linkedin.send_message(
    profile_link='https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe-friend-777262/', 
    message='Hi')
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks to me the missing module is from your VSCode extension. Maybe consider install or re-install all your VSCode extensions.